# Is there a name for the operation on graphs of functions that adds convex hull of certain points?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ that is defined on $\{0\}\cup[1/2,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1+x$ for $1/2\leq x\leq1$.

I want to define the following extension of this function that is defined on $[0,1]$: $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$ on $\{0\}\cup[1/2,1]$ and $\hat{f}(x)=2x$ on $(0,1/2)$ so that for each of the points in between $0$ and $1/2$, the graph of the new function is just the convex hull of $(0,f(0))$ and $(1/2,f(1/2))$.

Is there a name for this type of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sometimes called *piecewise linear extension*. A longer form is *extending $f$ in a piecewise linear way*, which may be more suitable when the original function has nonlinear pieces.

(Some say *piecewise affine* instead of *piecewise linear*, to emphasize it's $y=ax+b$ and not just $y=ax$. But I think in the presence of "piecewise" confusion is unlikely.)